# Database check before applying windows updates

Tags: powershell

Here is what I'm trying to do.

1. Query a DB to check for a job running
2. If no job is running then run Windows updates
3. If there is a job running it populates the variable
4. If no job is running then the variable stays null.

The problem I'm running into is that if an error happens on the query the variable stays null which will then run Windows updates.

I'm looking for ideas how to properly run this check and only run Windows updates if the variable is null.

```
  $result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance  'ipaddress,port' -Database 'instance' -Query $testQuery -QueryTimeout 15


if (!$result)
{
    Get-WUInstall -WindowsUpdate Software -AcceptAll
}
```

Comment: Why don't you query for string (job name) and test it after ?

Comment: we have to query a table to see if it has data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If assigning `$result` can give you an error, then I would just track the `$error` variable like so:

```
$error.clear()
$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance  'ipaddress,port' -Database 'instance' -Query $testQuery -QueryTimeout 15


if (!$result -and !$error)
{
    Get-WUInstall -WindowsUpdate Software -AcceptAll
}
```

**Test Case: No Errors and No Result**

```
$error.clear()
$result = $null
if (!$result -and !$error) {
Write-Host "Updating Windows..."
}

Updating Windows...
```

**Test Case: Error on Result**

```
$error.clear()
$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance  'ipaddress,port' -Database 'instance' -Query $testQuery -QueryTimeout 15
Invoke-Sqlcmd : The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

if (!$result -and !$error) {
Write-Host "Updating Windows...."
}

[bool]$error
True
[bool]$result
False
```

`$error.clear()` just empties the `$error` variable. This may not be completely wise if you are expecting that variable to track your errors throughout the script. I can only assume though since I've only seen a snippet of what you are doing.